# Is there a way to make Twig Extra Bundle allow for manual cache resets?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have just installed Twig Extra Bundle in my project. I generally prefer to do `rm -rf var/cache` in my projects rather than using the `cache:clear` command, but when I do that now, I get the following message when loading pages in the frontend:

> Warning:
> require(/usr/src/app/var/cache/dev/ContainerLjxQsxn/getRouting_LoaderService.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

This appears to be specifically related to Twig Extra Bundle, as removing the bundle removes the problem.

Is there a way I can keep Twig Extra Bundle while using the manual cache-clearing method I prefer?

Comment: Are you running `rm -rf` on a live system, that's serving pages at the same time?

Comment: In general, after clearing the cache, one would run `cache:warmup` to populate the cache.

Comment: @yivi no, this is on a development system.